# How to get default value of optional parameter of table function

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I know function name `TestOptionalParameter` and parameter name `number`.

parameter is optional and has default value, which can change later

the function is

```
CREATE FUNCTION TestOptionalParameter
(   
    @number int = 1
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
    SELECT @number * @number as sqr
)
```

how can I get value `1` from another function (or stored procedure) in the same database?

UPDATE

basically I don't need the result of function (I can get it with `select * from TestOptionalParameter(default)`);

I'm trying to know what is `default` value (1 in my example) and save it into variable (something like `declare x int = dbo.GetDefaultValue('TestOptionalParameter', '@number')`)

so I need equivalent of c# reflection ([Can I retrieve default value of parameter in method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60552130/can-i-retrieve-default-value-of-parameter-in-method))

Comment: its some thing unclear in last line.. how this function comes in picture of last line. There is something missing...

Answer (score 0):

The only way to get the parameter value seems to be to parse the `ROUTINE_DEFINITION` column of the `information_schema.routines` view as apparently the value isn't stored in any column, but rather evaluated from the definition at runtime.

If you know the parameter name in advance and the text in the procedure is well-formed then something like this could work. Note that in this example the substring returned is only 1 character long, so if the value can be longer you would have to extract a longer string.

```
SELECT 
    SUBSTRING
    (
       routine_definition, 
       PATINDEX('%@number int = %', ROUTINE_DEFINITION) + 14, 
       1
    ) ParamValue
FROM information_schema.routines 
WHERE routine_type = 'function' AND
      routine_name = 'TestOptionalParameter'
```

If you don't know the parameter names they can be found in the view referenced above, so it should be possible to find all default values by parsing the text definition, although it won't be easy.

Comment: thank you for answer. i found similar advice in msdn (sys.parameters: `SQL Server only maintains default values for CLR objects in this catalog view; therefore, has_default_value column has a value of 0 for Transact-SQL objects. To view the default value of a parameter in a Transact-SQL object, query the definition column of the sys.sql_modules catalog view, or use the OBJECT_DEFINITION system function.`, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176074(v=sql.100).aspx); i agree this won't be easy

Comment: @ASh Just fooled around a bit: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7e673/1 Writing a proper parser for the routine_definition would take some time, but shouldn't really be that difficult as the syntax is rather limited (and well-documented).

Comment: your function is excellent example for me to start with. i just expected there is something like `select default_value from sys.parameters where...` and i don't have to write a parser

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment reply I think you want call function in another function with the current parameter value pass.

So I think, this example might work for you.

```
CREATE FUNCTION TestOptionalParameter
(   
    @number int = 1
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
    SELECT @number * @number as sqr
)


CREATE FUNCTION TestOptionalParameterNew
(   
    @number int = 1
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
    SELECT @number * @number as total from [dbo].[TestOptionalParameter](@number)
)

select * from TestOptionalParameterNew(4)
```

Comment: basically i don't need the result of function (i can get it with `select * from TestOptionalParameter(default)`); i'm trying to know what is `default` value (1 in my example) and save it into variable (something like `declare x int = dbo.GetDefaultValue('TestOptionalParameter', '@number')`)

Answer (score -2):

You can use the below query to get the details about function

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.routines WHERE routine_type='function' AND routine_name ='TestOptionalParameter'
```

Comment: how you give answer.. what logic you apply for above answer.

Comment: @Ajay2707 I just gave the query which can be used to get the more details about the function, but am not able to answer that how to get the default value for the parameter.

Comment: @Rahul Bhati, this query doesn't return information about parameters of function

Comment: @Ash I agree, but it gives you the definition of Function in "Routine_Definition" column, may be you can use that to extract default value of parameter; I know it will not be a proper way of doing it.