# Can I retrieve default value of parameter in method?

Tags: c#, optional-parameters

Example:

```
public static double ComputeFoo(double nom, double den, double epsilon = 2.2e-16)
{
    double den1 = den == 0.0 ? epsilon : den;
    // den1 can still be zero if epsilon is zero
    // is there any way to retrieve 2.2e-16 here and assign it to den1?
    return nom/den1;
}
```

Is there a way to retrieve 2.2e-16 value and use it in method?

P.S.: I understand that for this particular example I can just call `ComputeFoo(nom, den1)`.

Comment: Store `2.2e-16` as a constant and refer to that in both your default value and wherever else you need it.

Comment: If you really want to get that value you can, through reflection, but I advise not to and do what @HereticMonkey mentioned already.

Answer (score 1):

You can set a constant value somewhere in your class, and pass it as the default value to the method. Once there you can check if the passed value is different from the constant or viceversa:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
     Test(0);
}

const int constantValue = 15;

static int Test(int testValue = constantValue)
{
    Console.WriteLine(testValue);
    Console.WriteLine(constantValue);

    return constantValue;
}
```

Note: constantValue must be a constant in order to build successfuly.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a different approach I mentioned above in my comment using `Reflection`; generic approach.

```
public static T GetDefaultOptionalParamValue<T, TClass>(string methodName, string paramName)
{
   if (typeof(TClass).GetMethod(methodName)?.GetParameters().Where(p => p.Attributes.HasFlag(ParameterAttributes.Optional) && 
       p.Attributes.HasFlag(ParameterAttributes.HasDefault) && p.Name == paramName)?.FirstOrDefault()?.DefaultValue is T myValue)
   {
      return myValue;
   }
      else { return default; }
}
```

You can this call it like so:

```
 var t = GetDefaultOptionalParamValue<double, ClassName>("ComputeFoo", "epsilon");
```

`t` value is `2.2E-16`

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to get the default value just from the method. A way this might work for you is making the default value a constant in your class. For example:

```
private const double epsilonDefault = 2.2e-16;

public static double ComputeFoo(double nom, double den, double epsilon = epsilonDefault)
{
    double den1 = den == 0.0 ? epsilon : den;
    if (den1 == 0) den1 = epsilonDefault;
    return nom / den1;
}
```

This way your default value is declared outside the method and available when you need it.

EDIT: To be complete, through reflection it is possible to do this but this seems too much for this question. An basic example of how to do this with reflection:

```
public static void Execute(int number = 10)
{
    Console.WriteLine(number);
    var defaultValue = typeof(Program)
            .GetMethod("Execute")
            .GetParameters()[0]
            .DefaultValue;
    Console.WriteLine(defaultValue); // 10
}
```

Comment: It is possible to get that default value, through reflection.

Comment: Reflection is too much for me for this task.
And sadly I can't change method's signature.

Comment: Hmm that might work indeed but it seems to me like that's more trouble then it's worth. This way is much simpler and cleaner.

Comment: @IgorStack this method does not change the signature of the method. Just the implementation of the signature.

Comment: @Xeno-D I agree, I am just saying, I don't agree with your statement.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ I agree. I made an edit to my original answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use reflection in `System.Diagnostics` to get access to the parameters.  This will get the default value of the third parameter of the enclosing function:

```
var x = new StackFrame(0).GetMethod().GetParameters()[2].DefaultValue;
```

Answer (score -1):

NO, you can't. The only default value that can be set is null

```
public static double ComputeFoo(double nom, double den, double ?epsilon )
{
    if (epsilon == null)
        epsilon = 2.2e-16

    double den1 = den == 0.0 ? epsilon : den;
    // den1 can still be zero if epsilon is zero
    // is there any way to retrieve 2.2e-16 here and assign it to den1?
    return nom/den1;
}
```